# Storing received Coordinates to a SQLite Database

Tags: android, sqlite, broadcastreceiver

I am receiving text messages of LAT and LONG on my phone number. Sample text:

LAT: 23.424076
LONG: 53.847818

I saw a tutorial on how to pass these data to SQLite Database. But, it reads all incoming messages. I wanted to get these data from a single number.

This tutorial https://pankajkakade101.wordpress.com/2013/04/11/read-each-new-incoming-sms-massages-in-android-and-put-it-into-database-using-service/

has 3 columns on a table. One for the address,date and body. I wanted my app to identify if the body(message) has lat and long, and get the floats, and put it on separate columns on my table.

It's confusing. Can you advice on what I should do?

Comment: Why don't you try parsing the message body and insert into DB if you have LAT LONG format in message body?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering you will always recieve the message text as **"LAT: "** and **"LONG: "**

```
String str = "LAT: 23.424076 LONG: 53.847818";
String[] splits = str.split("LAT: | LONG: ");

//test with
for(String s : splits)
    System.out.println(s);
   //Do your necessary jobs with the values over here
```